# Is this the correct database design? And why am I not

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have two tables, `projs` and `studies`, which refer to types of content on the website I'm building, and my latest task is that I need to add image carousels to each project and study (each row of `projs` and `studies`). Each project and study needs to have a related image carousel, in other words.

Where I am with my tables:

```
   projs
id  |    ...   
----------------
  1 |    ...     
  2 |    ...  
  3 |    ...  

   studies
id  |   ...  
-----------------
  1 |   ...
  2 |   ...
  3 |   ...
```

Where I want to be or think I should be: Something like

```
        projs
id  |    ...   | carid
------------------------
  1 |    ...   |   1
  2 |    ...   |   5
  3 |    ...   |   6

       studies
id  |   ...    | carid
-------------------------
  1 |   ...    |  2
  2 |   ...    |  3
  3 |   ...    |  4

     carousels
id  
------
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6

      carousel_assets
id  |   imgurl  | carid
  1 |    ...    |  1
  2 |    ...    |  2
  3 |    ...    |  1
  4 |    ...    |  1
  5 |    ...    |  5
  6 |    ...    |  2
  7 |    ...    |  3
  8 |    ...    |  4
  9 |    ...    |  3
 10 |    ...    |  4
 11 |    ...    |  3
 12 |    ...    |  2
 13 |    ...    |  2
```

where `carid` in each table is referencing the `id` of `carousels`.

**Question 1:** Is this the correct design????

The query I ran to create the two new tables was

```
CREATE TABLE carousels (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
CREATE TABLE carousel_assets (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, img VARCHAR (250), carid MEDIUMINT, FOREIGN KEY (carid) REFERENCES carousels(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

and now what I'm trying to do is add the `carid` columns to `projs` and `studies`. I tried

```
ALTER TABLE projs ADD carid MEDIUMUINT, FOREIGN KEY (carid) DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES carousels(id);
```

and got the very undescriptive error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'MEDIUMUINT, FOREIGN KEY (carid) DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES
>   carousels(id)' at line 1

**Question 2:** What is wrong with my query that caused that error?

On each page, so let's say, `/studies/?id=1` which is associated with carousel `2` in my example above, I need to get all the images to associated with that carousel, what should my query be?

Comment: you have `carid MEDIUMUINT` where it should be `carid MEDIUMINT`

Comment: _And why are you not_ what?

Answer (score 1):

The error is descriptive enough. You have a typo in `MEDIUMUINT`. Replace it with `MEDIUMINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE projs
ADD carid MEDIUMINT, FOREIGN KEY (carid) DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES carousels(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question 1. Is subjective, but as long as your rules for table design conventions are consistent then it's not bad.

Question 2. Is this the query you require?

```
ALTER TABLE projs ADD carid MEDIUMINT DEFAULT NULL, ADD FOREIGN KEY (carid) REFERENCES carousels(id);
```

Comment: Regarding Question 1, is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I think the design is just fine.